# Print new line from argument in command line

Tags: go

Morning All

I am trying to put together an ASCII art generator which accepts a word as a command line argument and prints out in ASCII art.  This is working so far however, instead of interpreting "\n" as a new line it is printing these characters as ASCII art as well.  Any ideas on how I can print a new line instead?

I have tried splitting the argument using code below but doesn't seem to do anything:

```
split := strings.Split(wordArg[1], "\n")
    fmt.Println(split)
```

This just prints out [hello\n].

I am printing using printf if there is anything I can add there to help interpret the \n as new line instead of as being part of the string.

I have added the whole code if it helps make sense of what I'm doing:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    //"strings"
    //"io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    wordArg := os.Args
    split := strings.Split(wordArg[1], "\n")
    fmt.Println(split)
    wordRune := []rune(wordArg[1])

    f, err := os.Open("standard.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    var lines []string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(wordRune); j++ {
            if lines[int(wordRune[j])*9-287+i] == "        " {
                fmt.Printf("        ")
            } else {
                fmt.Printf(lines[int(wordRune[j])*9-287+i])
            }
        }
        fmt.Print("\n")
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `fmt.Println()` prints a newline. `fmt.Println("\n")` also does that. Please show what's your input. Likely your input contains the `\n` sequence as-is (and not a single newline character).

Comment: Hi icza the input is from the command line so currently I am entering - go run . "hello\n" | cat -e

Comment: Passing `"hello\n"` from the command line will not pass `"hello"` followed by a newline character. It will pass `"hello"` followed by a backslash and `n` characters.

Comment: I know that's the problem the code I have been given to test requires that the "\n" be treated as a new line not the characters.  I need to find a way to convert it so it is treated as such.

Comment: If your input contains literal `\n`, then split like `strings.Split(wordArg[1], "\\n")` or `strings.Split(wordArg[1], \`\n\`)`.

Comment: Thanks icza I can now isolate the hello from the "\n" it's a start :)

Comment: @icza thank you. I just found out that THERE is an actual difference between `\n` and `\\n`

Answer (score 0):

***strings.ReplaceAll***

```
func ReplaceAll(str, oldstr, newstr string) string
```

The Replace All function does as the name suggests, and replaces all occurrences of oldstr with newstr within str.

```
strings.ReplaceAll(os.Args[1], "\\n", "\n")
```

This will return a string containing the first argument from the command line, with newlines in place of a literal backslash and letter n.